# Weird Output in for loop in C (Repetitive numbers)

Tags: c

This is my code for finding prime numbers.

```
int main (void){
    int p, d;
    _Bool isprime;

    for (p=2;p<=50;++p){
        isprime = 1;

        for (d=2;d<p;++d){
            if (p%d == 0)
                isprime = 0;

            if (isprime != 0)
                printf("%i ", p);
        }
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

The output of this program is

> 3 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 9 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 15 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 21 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 25 25 25 27 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 33 35 35 35 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 39 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 45 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 49 49 49 49 49

The numbers seem to be right, but they are repetitive. Is there something wrong with my code? Or is there something wrong with the compiler? Every time I use a for loop (not just this program) the output is like this. How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Read  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Move your print statement to the outermost loop. And in general, the cases where the *compiler* is wrong are negligibly rare relatively to one's code issues.

Comment: Walk through the code for a few values and see what happens. For example when `p == 5`, how many times is the inner loop called? How many times is the `printf` called?

Comment: Also, your observation that "The numbers seem to be right" is flawed.

Comment: @MrLister Yeap, there isn't 2, but I see a 9 a 21, some 25, 35, 45...

Comment: @MrLister @Bob__ That fixes itself when the `if` statement is moved outside. It's because it prints `p` before the inner loop has been run until it decides `p` is a prime number.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code, is that it prints `p` multiple times, for the same value of `p`. Like [Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh) stated in a comment, it's easily fixed by moving the `if` statement up a level, to the outer `for` loop. I also changed `is_prime` to a `bool` value, and edited how it's set.

```
int max_p = 50;
int p, d;
bool is_prime;

for (p = 2; p <= max_p; ++p) {
    is_prime = true;

    for (d = 2; d < p; ++d) {
        if (p % d == 0) {
            is_prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (is_prime) {
        printf("%i ", p);
    }
}
```

I will assume that I used C++ doesn't make a difference.

Comment: C has `bool` if you `#include <stdbool.h>`, so there's nothing C++ about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `printf` lines outside your inner loop.

Like this:

```
int main (void)
{
    int p, d;
    _Bool isprime;
    for (p=2;p<=50;++p){
        isprime = 1;
        for (d=2;d<p;++d){
            if (p%d == 0) {
                isprime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isprime)
            printf("%i ", p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `d * d <= p` in the condition of the inner loop to considerable effect.  It isn't critical for primes up to 50; it would be for primes up to even just 1,000 (it has a very big effect on the number of tests made).

Answer (score 0):

Others have given tips. Some of them are useful, some of them are not. The end goal is to print all prime numbers only. So checking if the number 6 is prime, we start with d = 2. So we check 6 % 2. Well that is equal to 0. We know that 6 is NOT prime. We should move on to 7. Instead we have incremented 2 to 3 and now we check again. 6 % 3... we do this for every number less than the number we are trying to check. This greatly adds to the computational complexity. This program runs very close to BigTheta(n^2). An easier way to run this would be a do-while loop or through the use of a break statement. Since you're using C, use an int as a bool marker (to prevent another lib import). Your inner loop would look like this:

```
    int is_prime = 1;
    for (d = 2; d < p; d++)
    {   
       if (p % d == 0)
       {
          is_prime = 0
          break;
       }
    }
    if (is_prime)
       printf("%d ", p);
```

There are additional methods of reducing the complexity, but those rely on better algorithm design moreso than more efficient code. For a beginner's project, think about why the current version of your code is inefficient (even if it was working properly). A lot of it comes with experience, but you shouldn't neglect individual code- and algorithm review.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use break statement. Without break, every time the calculation is performed, thus so many repetition in your original code. But even with break statement your code will generate many non desirable numbers/output instead of just generating prime numbers. So i have written following code for you. It will generate prime numbers as per your question. 
Use the following code for generating prime numbers upto 50.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ()
{

    int prime,i,k,j,max;
    printf("2\n");
    printf("3");

    for(i=4; i<max; i++)
    {
        if(i%2!=0 && i%3!=0 && i%5!=0 && i%7!=0)
        {
            prime=i;
            printf("\n%d",prime);
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if `break` was correctly added to the `if` using `{ }` this is still incorrect. See how every odd number is printed out at least once in the OPs original output? That would still happen in yours.

Comment: @Kevin, i only solved the repeatation issue using the break.. i have to add few more lines to generate the prime number code.

Comment: Now it will say that 49 is prime. It also isn't generic enough since you can't just change `50` to some higher value.

Comment: You say "You have to use `break` statement" but your code doesn't use it.  You should check ` && i % 7 != 0` as an extra condition since the only prime factor of 49 is 7.  Your printing is a bit eccentric; it is simplest and usually best to end every line with a newline — you don't print a trailing newline.